# Как вводить несколько телефонных номеров? Android

Tags: android, edittext

Android, поставлять запятые после шесть цифр, Пример: 123456, 456789, 123456
в Edittext

Comment: То есть вводите многа цифер, а устройство должно само запятые поставить? Так это через массив. А если вводите через запятую цифры, а вам надо их разбить и как то сохранить, то используйте editText.getText.split(“,“); Получите массив из подстрок разделенных запятой. Ну а там как хотите пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте добавить слушателя на изменение текста (TextWatcher) и через каждых 6 символов проставлять запятую (логику уже сам продумаете)